# JSON issue with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract consistently this portion of code (line 237 in page source) with python requests.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.classified = {"EverythingHere"
</script>
```

Yet I'm unable to parse it using the following code, while it works for every other "script" tags.

```
url = 'https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/new-real-estate-project-apartments/for-sale/auderghem/1160/8950161'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data=[]
for p in soup.find_all():
    for n in p:
        if n.name == 'script':
           data.append(str(n))
print(data[0])
```

Do I need to set up a time.sleep to let the parser loading the webpage or do I need to change something in my code ?

Any helps would be really appreciated ! Thanks.

Comment: You cant evaluate javascript function with requests and BeautifulSoup. You should use something like Selenium

Comment: @VictorErmakov It seems like you were right, Selenium is working. What's intriguing is the fact I was able to parse every script tag with python requests beside the one I wanted. Any ideas why ? Thanks anyway !

Comment: This one can be populate after some time, requests can't wait for it. It's just downloading html that on page before loading any javascript files/scripts.

Comment: What exactly is not working here? I don't have an issue pulling that. What are you getting in your print statement?

Comment: also, it's the last script tag that you are wanting: `print(data[-1])`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will try it with python requests again. I will mark as resolved in the meanwhile. :)

Comment: It's also possible you'll need the user-agent parameter in the headers. I included that in the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things:

You are unnecsarily using a nested loop to search for `'script'` tags. Rather than `find_all()` tags, then iterate through all the tags to find the ones that are `<script>`, you can do that right off the bat with `.find_all('script')`.

Secondly, it's the last `<script>` tag. You can either just call the `[-1]` index, or probably a better way incase for whatever reason it's not that last tag for another page, just get the one with `'window.classified'`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

url = 'https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/new-real-estate-project-apartments/for-sale/auderghem/1160/8950161'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

for p in soup.find_all('script'):
    if 'window.classified' in str(p):
        dataStr = str(p)
        #print(str(p))
        
# Parse the json
data = re.search('{.*}', dataStr).group(0)
jsonData = json.loads(data)
```

**Output:**

```
print(jsonData)
{'id': 8950161, 'cluster': {'minPrice': 240500, 'maxPrice': 521500, 'minSurface': 44, 'maxSurface': 104, 'projectInfo': {'constructor': None, 'groupId': 8950161, 'phase': None, 'projectName': 'DELTA VIEW', 'deliveryDate': '2022-10-01T00:00:00.000+0000', 'soldPercentage': 47, 'unitsDisplayMode': 'DETAILED'}, 'units': [{'type': 'APARTMENT', 'maxPrice': 521500, 'minPrice': 240500, 'minRoom': 0, 'maxRoom': 2, 'minSurface': 44, 'maxSurface': 104, 'soldCount': 36, 'items': [{'id': 8950204, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950212, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 35}, {'id': 8950213, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 35}, {'id': 8950217, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 35}, {'id': 8950222, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 35}, {'id': 8950223, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 35}, {'id': 8950170, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 48}, {'id': 8950192, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 66}, {'id': 8950203, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950205, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950211, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 35}, {'id': 8950218, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 35}, {'id': 8950220, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 35}, {'id': 8950226, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 66}, {'id': 8950175, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 44}, {'id': 8950179, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950182, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 70}, {'id': 8950183, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 70}, {'id': 8950216, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 35}, {'id': 8950162, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 2, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950202, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 2, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950244, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 2, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950171, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 44}, {'id': 8950194, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 2, 'price': 240500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950193, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 2, 'price': 240500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950195, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 3, 'price': 243500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950196, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 3, 'price': 243500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950206, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 4, 'price': 244500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950197, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 4, 'price': 245500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950198, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950207, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 5, 'price': 247500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950208, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 5, 'price': 247500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950224, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 2, 'price': 247500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 48}, {'id': 8950225, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 2, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 48}, {'id': 8950172, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 3, 'price': 248500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 44}, {'id': 8950199, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 5, 'price': 248500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950200, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 5, 'price': 248500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950209, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 6, 'price': 249500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950210, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 6, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950239, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 6, 'price': 250500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950248, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 6, 'price': 250500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950201, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 6, 'price': 250500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950242, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 3, 'price': 250500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 48}, {'id': 8950163, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 3, 'price': 250500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 48}, {'id': 8950164, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 3, 'price': 250500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 48}, {'id': 8950173, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 4, 'price': 250500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 44}, {'id': 8950166, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 4, 'price': 252500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 48}, {'id': 8950165, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 4, 'price': 252500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 48}, {'id': 8950174, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 5, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 44}, {'id': 8950167, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 5, 'price': 255500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 48}, {'id': 8950168, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 5, 'price': 255500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 48}, {'id': 8950176, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 2, 'price': 255500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950169, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 6, 'price': 257500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 48}, {'id': 8950178, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 0, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 46}, {'id': 8950177, 'subtype': 'FLAT_STUDIO', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 4, 'price': 260500, 'bedroomCount': 0, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 47}, {'id': 8950190, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 3, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 66}, {'id': 8950188, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 2, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 66}, {'id': 8950189, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 3, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 66}, {'id': 8950187, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 2, 'price': 312000, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 66}, {'id': 8950191, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 4, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 66}, {'id': 8950181, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 2, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 70}, {'id': 8950180, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 3, 'price': 335500, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 70}, {'id': 8950243, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 3, 'price': 335500, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 70}, {'id': 8950185, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 5, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 70}, {'id': 8950241, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 5, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 70}, {'id': 8950184, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 4, 'price': 338500, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 70}, {'id': 8950186, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'SOLD', 'floor': 6, 'price': None, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 70}, {'id': 8950240, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 4, 'price': 338500, 'bedroomCount': 1, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 70}, {'id': 8950227, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 0, 'price': 501500, 'bedroomCount': 2, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 102}, {'id': 8950228, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 0, 'price': 504500, 'bedroomCount': 2, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 102}, {'id': 8950229, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 0, 'price': 506500, 'bedroomCount': 2, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 102}, {'id': 8950231, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 7, 'price': 511500, 'bedroomCount': 2, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 104}, {'id': 8950230, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 0, 'price': 511500, 'bedroomCount': 2, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 102}, {'id': 8950233, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 8, 'price': 513500, 'bedroomCount': 2, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 104}, {'id': 8950234, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 9, 'price': 516500, 'bedroomCount': 2, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 104}, {'id': 8950236, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 0, 'price': 518500, 'bedroomCount': 2, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 104}, {'id': 8950238, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 11, 'price': 521500, 'bedroomCount': 2, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 104}, {'id': 8950247, 'subtype': 'APARTMENT', 'saleStatus': 'AVAILABLE', 'floor': 11, 'price': 521500, 'bedroomCount': 2, 'realEstateProjectPhase': None, 'surface': 104}]}], 'bedroomRange': '1 - 2', 'surfaceRange': '44 - 104'}, 'customers': [{'id': 1364801, 'type': 'REAL_ESTATE_AGENCY', 'email': 'victoire_1490@importfrommedia.be', 'logoUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/logos/1364801.gif?cache=201721090326Z', 'phoneNumber': '+32 2 375 10 10', 'mobileNumber': None, 'name': 'Victoire (Immobilier Neuf)', 'website': None, 'location': {'country': 'Belgium', 'region': None, 'province': 'Brussels', 'district': 'Brussels', 'locality': 'Uccle', 'postalCode': '1180', 'street': 'Chaussée de Waterloo 1382', 'number': None, 'box': None, 'propertyName': None, 'floor': None, 'latitude': 50.8261604, 'longitude': 4.4461589, 'approximated': None, 'regionCode': None, 'type': None, 'hasSeaView': None, 'pointsOfInterest': None, 'placeName': None}, 'ipiNo': None, 'isOwner': True, 'contactHoursMobile': 'anytime', 'contactHoursLandline': 'anytime', 'salesRepresentative': None}], 'premiumProjectPage': {'medias': None, 'options': None, 'promoter': None, 'tabs': None}, 'flags': {'isPublicSale': False, 'isNewClassified': False, 'isNewPrice': False, 'isNewlyBuilt': True, 'isNotarySale': None, 'isLifeAnnuitySale': False, 'adQuality': None, 'date': None, 'priceSqm': None, 'price': None, 'default': None, 'isSoldOrRented': False, 'isLowEnergy': None, 'percentSold': 47, 'isPassiveHouse': None, 'isNewRealEstateProject': True, 'isAnInteractiveSale': None, 'isUnderOption': None}, 'media': {'pictures': [{'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_1.gif?cache=20210217035932', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_1.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_1.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_2.gif?cache=20210217035932', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_2.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_2.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_3.gif?cache=20210217035932', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_3.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_3.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_4.gif?cache=20210217040440', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_4.jpg?cache=20210217040440', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_4.jpg?cache=20210217040440', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_5.gif?cache=20210217035932', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_5.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_5.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_6.gif?cache=20210217035932', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_6.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_6.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_7.gif?cache=20210217035932', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_7.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_7.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_8.gif?cache=20210217035933', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_8.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_8.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_9.gif?cache=20210217035933', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_9.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_9.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_0.gif?cache=20210217035932', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_0.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_0.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'isVertical': True}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_A.gif?cache=20210217035933', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_A.jpg?cache=20210217035932', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_A.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'isVertical': True}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_B.gif?cache=20210217035933', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_B.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_B.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_C.gif?cache=20210217035933', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_C.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_C.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_D.gif?cache=20210217035933', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_D.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_D.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_E.gif?cache=20210217035933', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_E.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_E.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_F.gif?cache=20210217035933', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_F.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_F.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_G.gif?cache=20210217035933', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_G.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_G.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_H.gif?cache=20210217035933', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_H.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_H.jpg?cache=20210217035933', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_I.gif?cache=20200923031600', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_I.jpg?cache=20200923031600', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_I.jpg?cache=20200923031600', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_J.gif?cache=20200923031600', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_J.jpg?cache=20200923031600', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_J.jpg?cache=20200923031600', 'isVertical': False}, {'smallUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_K.gif?cache=20200923031600', 'mediumUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/M_8950161_K.jpg?cache=20200923031600', 'largeUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/photos/0/8/9/5/0/1/6/1/8950161_K.jpg?cache=20200923031600', 'isVertical': False}], 'virtualTourUrl': None, 'floorPlans': None, 'specifications': None, 'virtualExperienceUrl': 'https://youtu.be/D8wua7Z_Pe8'}, 'property': {'type': 'APARTMENT_GROUP', 'subtype': 'APARTMENT_GROUP', 'title': 'BUY NOW AND PAY IN 2022', 'description': 'This new project (available at the end of 2022) is ideally located in the new district of Chirec / Delta, near the Université Libre de Bruxelles (ULB and VUB) and consists of 70 units, from studios to 2-bedroom apartments. Most units have a terrace and / or a view of the green surroundings and the green rooftops. The building has a passive energy label. PEB A+ A bicycle storage is available on the 1st floor. Parkings and cellars are also provided at the same floor, at an additional cost. Sale under the mixed system of registration on the land value and VAT on the construction value. Choose your apartment now and pay for it at the delivery,  at no extra cost! Contact us for more information about this project: 02 3751010 / new@victoire.be', 'name': None, 'isHolidayProperty': None, 'bedroomCount': None, 'bedrooms': [], 'bathroomCount': None, 'bathrooms': [], 'location': {'country': 'Belgium', 'region': 'Brussels', 'province': 'Brussels', 'district': 'Brussels', 'locality': 'Auderghem', 'postalCode': '1160', 'street': 'Boulevard du Triomphe', 'number': '201', 'box': None, 'propertyName': None, 'floor': None, 'latitude': 50.816023, 'longitude': 4.3999304, 'approximated': None, 'regionCode': 'BRUSSELS', 'type': None, 'hasSeaView': None, 'pointsOfInterest': [{'type': 'SCHOOL', 'distance': 150}, {'type': 'SHOPS', 'distance': 200}, {'type': 'TRANSPORT', 'distance': 0}], 'placeName': 'Projets Bruxelles Est'}, 'netHabitableSurface': None, 'roomCount': None, 'attic': None, 'hasAttic': None, 'basement': None, 'hasBasement': None, 'hasDressingRoom': None, 'diningRoom': None, 'hasDiningRoom': None, 'building': None, 'propertyCertificates': None, 'hasCaretakerOrConcierge': None, 'hasDisabledAccess': None, 'hasLift': None, 'constructionPermit': {'constructionType': None, 'floodZoneType': 'NON_FLOOD_ZONE', 'isObtained': None, 'hasObligationToConstruct': None, 'hasPlotDivisionAuthorization': None, 'hasPossiblePriorityPurchaseRight': None, 'isBreachingUrbanPlanningRegulation': None, 'floodZoneIconUrl': None, 'totalBuildableGroundFloorSurface': 0, 'urbanPlanningInformation': None}, 'energy': None, 'kitchen': None, 'land': None, 'laundryRoom': None, 'hasLaundryRoom': None, 'livingRoom': None, 'hasLivingRoom': False, 'isFirstOccupation': None, 'hasBalcony': None, 'hasBarbecue': None, 'hasGarden': None, 'gardenSurface': None, 'gardenOrientation': None, 'parkingCountIndoor': 1, 'parkingCountOutdoor': 1, 'parkingCountClosedBox': None, 'hasAirConditioning': None, 'hasArmoredDoor': None, 'hasVisiophone': None, 'hasSecureAccessAlarm': None, 'hasTVCable': None, 'hasDoorPhone': None, 'hasInternet': None, 'showerRoomCount': None, 'showerRooms': [], 'specificities': None, 'toiletCount': None, 'toilets': [], 'hasFitnessRoom': None, 'hasTennisCourt': None, 'hasSwimmingPool': None, 'hasSauna': None, 'hasJacuzzi': None, 'hasHammam': None, 'bedroomSurface': None, 'alternativeDescriptions': {'fr': "Ce projet (disponible fin 2022), bien situé dans le nouveau quartier du Chirec/Delta, et des facultés universitaires ULB/VUB, comporte 70 logements allant principalement du studio à l’appartement 2 chambres. Très urbain, les logements bénéficient néanmoins pour la plupart de terrasses et/ou de vues sur la verdure et les toits verdurisés. Le bÃtiment est passif et profite de l’alimentation en chauffage co-génération du Chirec. PEB A+ Le local vélo est disponible au 1er et  les parkings et les caves au © 1 sont en supplément.   Vente sous droits d'enregistrement sur le terrain et sous régime TVA sur la construction,  Réservez votre appartement maintenant et payez-le à la livraison, sans augmentation de prix ! Consultez-nous sans attendre pour tout détail sur ce projet : 02 3751010 / new@victoire.be", 'nl': "Dit nieuwbouwproject (beschikbaar eind 2022) is uitstekend gelegen in de nieuwe stadswijk Chirec/Delta, nabij de Vrije Universiteit Brussel en omvat 70 wooneenheden gaande van studio's tot appartementen met 2 slaapkamers. De meeste units hebben een terras en/of zicht op de groene omgeving en de groene daken. Het gebouw heeft een passief energielabel. EPC A+ Een fietsenberging is voorzien op de 1e verdieping. Hier zijn ook parkings en kelders voorzien, dit tegen een meerprijs.  Verkoop onder het gemend stelsel van registratierechten op de grondwaarde en BTW op de constructiewaarde. Kies nu uw appartement en betaal het aan de levering Ã zonder meerprijs! Raadpleeg ons voor meer informatie over dit project: 02 3751010 / new@victoire.be"}, 'habitableUnitCount': None, 'fireplaceCount': None, 'fireplaceExists': False, 'hasTerrace': None, 'terraceSurface': None, 'terraceOrientation': None}, 'publication': {'creationDate': '2020-09-23T03:12:09.000+0000', 'expirationDate': '2021-04-30T21:59:59.000+0000', 'publisherId': None, 'visualisationOption': 'XL', 'lastModificationDate': '2021-04-22T02:36:15.000+0000'}, 'transaction': {'type': 'FOR_SALE', 'subtype': 'BUY_REGULAR', 'availabilityPeriodType': 'AT_DELIVERY', 'availabilityDate': '2022-10-01T00:00:00.000+0000', 'certificates': {'carbonEmission': 40, 'hasElectricalInstallationComplianceCertificate': None, 'primaryEnergyConsumptionPerSqm': 45, 'primaryEnergyConsumptionYearly': None, 'epcDescription': None, 'epcReference': 'A+', 'epcScore': 'A', 'epcUrl': 'https://static.immoweb.be/en/pics/bxlA3.gif'}, 'rental': None, 'sale': {'price': None, 'vatType': 'VAT_EXCLUDED', 'cadastralIncome': 0, 'publicSale': None, 'pricePerSqm': None, 'oldPrice': None, 'lifeAnnuity': None, 'hasStartingPrice': True, 'isFurnished': None, 'homeToBuild': None}, 'investor': {'isInvestmentProperty': False, 'currentMonthlyRentalIncome': None, 'currentReturnOnInvestment': None, 'expectedMonthlyRentalIncome': None, 'expectedMonthlyRentalIncomeDescription': None, 'expectedReturnOnInvestment': None, 'habitableUnitCount': None, 'occupancyRate': None}}, 'priceType': None, 'price': {'type': 'group_sale', 'mainValue': None, 'alternativeValue': None, 'additionalValue': None, 'oldValue': None, 'minRangeValue': 240500, 'maxRangeValue': 521500, 'mainDisplayPrice': '€240,500 - €521,500', 'HTMLDisplayPrice': '<span aria-hidden="true">€240,500 - €521,500</span>', 'alternativeDisplayPrice': '', 'oldDisplayPrice': None, 'shortDisplayPrice': '240.5K - 521.5K €', 'accessibilityPrice': 'From 240500€ To 521500€', 'label': 'Min price - Max price', 'language': 'en'}, 'externalReference': '4161726', 'isBookmarked': False, 'hasSectionsArray': {'hasGeneralSection': True, 'hasInteriorSection': False, 'hasExteriorSection': False, 'hasFacilitiesSection': False, 'hasEnergySection': True, 'hasPlanningSection': True, 'hasFinancialSection': True, 'hasPublicSaleSection': False}, 'unitGroupings': [], 'displayFlags': {'main': None, 'secondary': ['new_real_estate_project', 'percent_sold'], 'percentSold': 47}, 'statistics': {'bookmarkCount': 18, 'viewCount': 2604, 'alertPrice': None, 'creationDate': None, 'description': None, 'isAlertEmailSet': None, 'rating': None, 'wasOwnerContacted': None, 'wasPropertyVisited': None}}
```